# Selenium IDE error: "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer."

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-ide

I'd like to run a test case of Selenium IDE using Google Chrome. The test case has passed in Firefox but I need to run it in chrome. Using command prompt, chrome has opened but it wasn't able to run the TC as the error blocked it. Please advise how should this be fixed, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this issue resolved by: 
1. Run selenium server thru command prompt and specify ChromeDriverServer 
2. Indicate "chrome" in  Selenium IDE > Options - WebDriver 
3. Run the TC as normal

It has opened and run successfully in chrome.